# Automatic generation and renewal of Let's Encrypt certificates on Google HTTPS Load Balancer

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Google Kubernetes Engine and have the Google HTTPS Load Balancer as my ingress.

Right now the load balancer uses Let's Encrypt certificates. However, is there a simple way to ensure that the certificates are automatically renewed prior to their 90 day expiry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now use "Google-managed SSL certificates" which is currently in beta: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#managed-certs

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified how you configured Let's Encrypt for your load balancer. Right now Google does not offer this for you, so I assume you mean you set the Let's Encrypt certificate yourself. In this case, Google can't renew your certificate.

Until there's an official support you can install a third-party add-on like `cert-manager` to automate certificate configuration and renewal. There's a GKE tutorial for doing this at https://github.com/ahmetb/gke-letsencrypt.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I saw cert-manager but it has warnings about not using for production services yet. I was hoping for something that was production ready. (Maybe cert-manager is but the developers are very cautious...)

Comment: Lego is another 3rd party tool available: https://thornelabs.net/2016/11/08/use-lego-gcloud-dns-and-dns-challenge-to-generate-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificates.html.